# How can I burn a CD compatible with original iMac?

Tags: windows, imac

I bought an original iMac at a rummage sale today, running Mac OS 8.6, PowerPC G3, 333mhz.

I have two classic Mac games in Mac format on a Windows 7 PC that I am trying to transfer to the iMac. One of the games is an image file in DMG format, which I have converted to ISO, and burnt to CD-R.

When I examine the CD-R on another Windows 7 machine, the files are intact. But when I insert into the iMac, I get the error "The disc is unreadable by this computer. Would you like to initialize the disc?" with two buttons, Initialize (format) or Eject.

I burned at 48x write speed, using MODE 1. The disc itself is a 700 mb Memorex.

I originally was to transfer the files over the internet, but there is no wi-fi support on the iMac and it's too far to hardwire via ethernet to my router.

Any ideas or suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to burn a hybrid disc with both ISO9660 (and Joliet, Rock Ridge, etc.) and HFS directories.

Comment: Thank you, do you know off-hand a burning solution that can do this? I used Windows built-in to burn the first disc and as I'm sure you're aware, no such options are available.

Comment: Unfortunately no. But I can tell you that anything built-in is unlikely to support this.

Comment: Thanks, +1 and closed. For others with this problem, the freeware `ImgBurn` for Windows was able to burn a hybrid disc as suggested. http://www.imgburn.com/

Comment: @SetSailMedia When you find that the answer provided is just short of what you need, and a little more research is needed, you can add the found results to the answer by editing the answer with the details you found.